# $\operatorname{Rank}(A)\leq \operatorname{Rank}(AB).$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices and let $B$ be invertible. I want to show that $\operatorname{Rank}(A)\leq \operatorname{Rank}(AB).$

So if we take $x\in \operatorname{Col}(A)$ then we have $x=Av$ for some $v\in \mathbb{R}^n.$ I need to show that this is in $\operatorname{Col}(AB)$ though.

Where do I need to go from here?

Comment: Since $B$ is invertible, there exists $y$ such that $By=v$, innit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has even more.
Think of $A$, $B$ as the matrices of endomorphisms $u$, $v$ of $K^n$ ($K$ = base field).

‘$B$ is invertible’ means $v$ is an automorphism of $K^n$. Now $\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rank}\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{Im}\rk A=\dim(\Im u)$, $\rk B=\dim(\Im v)$ and  $\rk AB=\dim(\Im (u\circ v))$.

As $v$ is an automorphism, $\Im v=K^n$, so $\Im (u\circ v)=\Im(u)$, whence
$$\rk(AB)=\dim(\Im (u\circ v))=\dim(\Im u)=\rk(A).$$

*Note:*

If no hypothesis is made on $B$, it is true that $\Im(u\circ v)\subset \Im u$, so we have the following inequality in general:
$$\rk(AB)\le \rk A ,\quad\text{and also}\quad \rk(AB)\le \rk B.$$

Comment: Another way that is more computational and less conceptual: 1. Elementary column operations do not change the rank, 2. Reduce $AB$ to $A$ by elementary operations that transform $B$ to $I$.

Comment: I would say ‘less geometric’ rather than ‘less conceptual’. Yes, I thought of that explanation too, but finally preferred the other. It's just a matter of taste.

Comment: @i707107 Could you explain the more computational way of doing it?

Comment: Elementary column operations such as column replacement, column swapping, and scalar multiplication to a column, do not chance the rank. Also, any invertible matrix $B$ can be reduced to the identity matrix $I$ using a series $E_1$, $\ldots$, $E_p$ of elementary column operations. Then $B^{-1}=E_1E_2\cdots E_p$. We multiply these to $AB$ then it becomes $AB E_1E_2\cdots E_p = AB B^{-1} = A$. Therefore, $rank AB = rank A$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By [Sylvester's Rank Theorem](http://ps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties), we have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Rank}(A) +\operatorname{Rank}(B) \leq \operatorname{Rank}(AB)+n.
\end{align}